# Get lines between pattern1 and pattern2 into a seperate file including the line with pattern1 in shell

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a text file with thousands of lines as below

```
`DEFINE OBJECT('OBJECT.TOPIC') +
*  ALTDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  ALTTIME(00.56.38) +
   DESCR('topic object') +
   GET(ENABLED) +
   PUT(ENABLED) +
   PROPCTL(COMPAT) +
   TARGTYPE(TOPIC) +
   REPLACE
DEFINE OBJECT('OBJECT1') +
*  CRDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  CRTIME(00.56.38) +
*  CURDEPTH(0) +
   CUSTOM(' ') +
   DESCR('TEST') +
   DISTL(NO) +
   PROCESS(' ') +
   SHARE +
   USAGE(NORMAL) +
   REPLACE
DEFINE OBJECT('OBJECT2') +
*  ALTDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  ALTTIME(00.56.38) +
*  CURDEPTH(0) +
   CUSTOM(' ') +
   DESCR('TEST') +
   DISTL(NO) +
   PROCESS(' ') +
   SHARE +
   USAGE(NORMAL) +
   REPLACE
DEFINE OBJECT('TCOBJECT1') +
*  CRDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  CRTIME(00.56.38) +
*  CURDEPTH(0) +
   CUSTOM(' ') +
   DESCR('TEST') +
   DISTL(NO) +
   PROCESS(' ') +
   SHARE +
   USAGE(NORMAL) +
   REPLACE
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT2') +
   GROUP('user1') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('TCOBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user3') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user1') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user2') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user3') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)`
```

Now, i want to get the blocks containing matching the pattern OBJECT1.

```
`DEFINE OBJECT('OBJECT1') +
*  CRDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  CRTIME(00.56.38) +
*  CURDEPTH(0) +
   CUSTOM(' ') +
   DESCR('TEST') +
   DISTL(NO) +
   PROCESS(' ') +
   SHARE +
   USAGE(NORMAL) +
   REPLACE
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user1') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user2') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user3') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)`
```

I have tried with awk and sed to get atleast the first part. but it's not stopping after the first match of pattern2. I am running these commands just to get the first block atleast..

```
awk '/OBJECT1/ {p=1}; p; $0=="REPLACE" {p=0}' objlist.txt > obj1list.txt 

awk '$0=="OBJECT1" {p=1}; p; $0=="REPLACE" {p=0}' objlist.txt > obj1list.txt

cat objlist.txt | sed  -n '/OBJECT1/p;/REPLACE/q' > obj1list.txt
```

But these dont work.Please help

As per the suggested answer, i am using **awk -vRS="[^+]\n" 'BEGIN{printf "`"}/\/{printf $0 RT}'** and getting the required output. However now i want to remove the block containing user2 and user3 from the output obtained by using the above command.

Comment: Hi..I know this is old, but is there a way i can remove the block containing user3 after getting the blocks containing OBJECT1 in this question. I am trying with awk -vRS="[^+]\n" 'BEGIN{printf ""}/\<'user3'\>/{printf " " $0 RT}'|sed '/^\s*$/d' but this isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -vRS="[^+]\n" 'BEGIN{printf "`"}/\<OBJECT1\>/{printf $0 RT}' a
```

Comment: thanks. This works perfectly fine. One more question though, is there anyway i can remove the REPLACE in the output?

Comment: REPLACE line? like this? awk -vRS="[^+]\n" 'BEGIN{printf "`"}/\<OBJECT1\>/{if(!sub(" *REPLAC","")){$0=$0 RT}printf $0}' a

Comment: Hi..I know this is old, but is there a way i can remove the block containing user3 after getting the blocks containing OBJECT1 in this question. I am trying with `awk -vRS="[^+]\n" 'BEGIN{printf ""}/\<'user3'\>/{printf " " $0 RT}'|sed '/^\s*$/d'` but this isn't working.

Comment: can you help me here?

Comment: like this? awk -vRS="[^+]\n" 'BEGIN{printf "`"}/\<OBJECT1\>/&&!/\<user3\>/{printf $0 RT}' file . The end you maybe add Backticks

Comment: I am into another issue with this. What if the text has objects like OBJECT1.TC. Then your command gives me line from both OBJECT1 and OBJECT1.TC.

Comment: or if i just search for something like OBJECT, it will give all OBJECT1/2 etc. So what I am trying to get is the exact match for the pattern. I tried ^OBJECT1$, \OBJECT1 but these eat up the blocks of output. Similarly with grep -w.

Comment: Hi, Can you offer any help?

Comment: awk -vRS="[^+]\n" 'BEGIN{printf "`"}/\047OBJECT1\047/{printf $0 RT}'

Comment: is there a way to get the output for OBJECT1 only if it is preceeded by DEFINE OBJECT or PROFILE? In other words, OBJECT1 comes up in multiple other places but i want the output to only show when it comes with DEFINE OBJECT or PROFILE. –

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue! (with little help from sed)

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^* ])/\n\1/' file | awk -v RS= '/OBJECT1/'
```

will print

```
DEFINE OBJECT('OBJECT1') +
*  CRDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  CRTIME(00.56.38) +
*  CURDEPTH(0) +
   CUSTOM(' ') +
   DESCR('TEST') +
   DISTL(NO) +
   PROCESS(' ') +
   SHARE +
   USAGE(NORMAL) +
   REPLACE
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user1') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user2') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user3') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)`
```

ps. Note that the start quote is not printed since it's not on the extracted line.

For more targeted matches you can combine the quote as part of the pattern.  However, in awk it has special meaning and should be treated.  I use the following approach.

```
$ ... | awk -v RS= -vq="'" '$0 ~ q"OBJECT1"q'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, karafka. I actually forgot. There are other objects that contain OBJECT1 in their name ex. TCOBJECT1 and have similar line. So, its also outputting the line for that object. Is there anyway to search for that exact pattern?

Comment: for that you can use the quote as part of the pattern.  see my update.

Comment: That's the problem, karafka. With quote, the output is only `DEFINE OBJECT('OBJECT1') +` and `PROFILE('OBJECT1') +`. I still the output as in my original post. Let me update my original post so that it's clear what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="DEFINE OBJECT"}{if($1~/\('\''OBJECT1'\''\)/){print$0}}' my_file
```

Comment: only prints block containing (OBJECT1)...hope this is what you are looking to do

Comment: Hi Xorg, i wanted the block following OBJECT1. Your command is only giving me the lines containing OBJECT1. A-Ray's command is working great to give me the necessary outpout.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\w/!{H;$!d};x;/\bOBJECT1\b/p;x;h;d' file
```

If it is not the start of a record append it to the hold space (HS) and if it is not the last line delete it. Otherwise it is either the start of a record or the last line in which case: check the HS for the required string and print if found and then replace the HS with the start of the record.