# Using awk to get the exact pattern match and the blocks following it

Tags: shell, awk

I had asked this question earlier. 
[Get lines between pattern1 and pattern2 into a seperate file including the line with pattern1 in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289518/get-lines-between-pattern1-and-pattern2-into-a-seperate-file-including-the-line/33294569?noredirect=1#comment55354166_33294569)

And am using awk to get what i want as suggested by @A-Ray. However, earlier i used to run a command against each object(about 500 of them) and then use awk to get what i wanted. Now, instead of doing that, i am trying to spit everything into a text file and use awk to get lines for individual objects.

So, my text file is

```
DEFINE OBJECT('OBJECT.TOPIC') +
*  ALTDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  ALTTIME(00.56.38) +
   DESCR('topic object') +
   GET(ENABLED) +
   PUT(ENABLED) +
   PROPCTL(COMPAT) +
   TARGTYPE(TOPIC) +
   REPLACE
DEFINE OBJECT('OBJECT1') +
*  CRDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  CRTIME(00.56.38) +
*  CURDEPTH(0) +
   CUSTOM(' ') +
   DESCR('TEST') +
   DISTL(NO) +
   PROCESS(' ') +
   SHARE +
   USAGE(NORMAL) +
   REPLACE
DEFINE OBJECT('OBJECT2') +
*  ALTDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  ALTTIME(00.56.38) +
*  CURDEPTH(0) +
   CUSTOM(' ') +
   DESCR('TEST') +
   DISTL(NO) +
   PROCESS(' ') +
   SHARE +
   USAGE(NORMAL) +
   REPLACE
DEFINE OBJECT('TCOBJECT1') +
*  CRDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  CRTIME(00.56.38) +
*  CURDEPTH(0) +
   CUSTOM(' ') +
   DESCR('TEST') +
   DISTL(NO) +
   PROCESS(' ') +
   SHARE +
   USAGE(NORMAL) +
   REPLACE
DEFINE OBJECT('OBJECT1TC') +
*  CRDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  CRTIME(00.56.38) +
*  CURDEPTH(0) +
   CUSTOM(' ') +
   DESCR('TEST') +
   DISTL(NO) +
   PROCESS(' ') +
   SHARE +
   USAGE(NORMAL) +
   REPLACE

DEFINE OBJECT('OBJECT1.TC') +
*  CRDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  CRTIME(00.56.38) +
*  CURDEPTH(0) +
   CUSTOM(' ') +
   DESCR('TEST') +
   DISTL(NO) +
   PROCESS(' ') +
   SHARE +
   USAGE(NORMAL) +
   REPLACE

SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT2') +
   GROUP('user1') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('TCOBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user3') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user1') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user2') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user3') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
   SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT2') +
   GROUP('user3') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
   SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1.TC') +
   GROUP('user1') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1.TC') +
   GROUP('user2') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
```

And I want the output as

```
DEFINE OBJECT('OBJECT1') +
*  CRDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  CRTIME(00.56.38) +
*  CURDEPTH(0) +
   CUSTOM(' ') +
   DESCR('TEST') +
   DISTL(NO) +
   PROCESS(' ') +
   SHARE +
   USAGE(NORMAL) +
   REPLACE
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user1') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user2') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
```

So if you look at the output i want, i am getting blocks only for OBJECT1 and removing anything with OBJECT1 and user3.

So the command i am using for this is

```
cat testawk.txt|awk -vRS="[^+]\n" 'BEGIN{printf ""}/\<OBJECT\>/&&!/\<'user3'\>/{printf $0 RT}'
```

But by using the above command i get the output as

```
DEFINE OBJECT('OBJECT1') +
*  CRDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  CRTIME(00.56.38) +
*  CURDEPTH(0) +
   CUSTOM(' ') +
   DESCR('TEST') +
   DISTL(NO) +
   PROCESS(' ') +
   SHARE +
   USAGE(NORMAL) +
   REPLACE
DEFINE OBJECT('OBJECT1.TC') +
*  CRDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  CRTIME(00.56.38) +
*  CURDEPTH(0) +
   CUSTOM(' ') +
   DESCR('TEST') +
   DISTL(NO) +
   PROCESS(' ') +
   SHARE +
   USAGE(NORMAL) +
   REPLACE
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user1') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user2') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
   SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1.TC') +
   GROUP('user1') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1.TC') +
   GROUP('user2') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
```

Is there a way to get an exact match for OBJECT1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

handling quotes is hard, better to externalize them from the script.  Using quotes eliminate the need to set the word boundaries as well (quotes are the boundaries).

```
$ awk -vRS='[^+]\n' -vk="'OBJECT1'" -vu="'user3'" '$0~k && $0!~u{printf "%s",$0 RT}' file

DEFINE OBJECT('OBJECT1') +
*  CRDATE(2015-09-22) +
*  CRTIME(00.56.38) +
*  CURDEPTH(0) +
   CUSTOM(' ') +
   DESCR('TEST') +
   DISTL(NO) +
   PROCESS(' ') +
   SHARE +
   USAGE(NORMAL) +
   REPLACE
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user1') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
SET RECORD +
   PROFILE('OBJECT1') +
   GROUP('user2') +
   AUTHADD(change,delete,display,alter)
```

Comment: is there a way to get the output for OBJECT1 only if it is preceeded by DEFINE OBJECT or PROFILE? In other words, OBJECT1 comes up in multiple other places but i want the output to only show when it comes with DEFINE OBJECT or PROFILE.

Comment: yes you add another pattern match to the condition, something like `$0~/DEFINE_OBJECT|PROFILE/ && $0~k && ..`